# store value of my Java function return String In JavaScript variable

Tags: java, javascript, html, css

I am developing a web application in JSP. I made this page with JSP, CSS and HTML. There are six buttons. Every button calls a JavaScript method, so the first button is a call of the  `par()` method.

```
  <html>
<head>
<title>Welcome   d To Student University</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/stlogin.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/background.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/back.css">
<script src="StInfo.jsp">
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class=main>
    <div class=blank></div>
    <div class=welcome><h1 class=welcome><center>Welcome Student</center></h1>
    <div class=logout><a href='logout.jsp?value=st'>Logout</a></div></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class=menu>
    <div class=leftgap>.
    </div>
    <div class=option>
    <center>
    <button type="button" onclick=par() class="Bt_menu">Check Parsnal Info</button>
    </center>
    </div>
    <div class=option>
    <center>
    <button type="button" onclick=faculty() class="Bt_menu">All Faculty Details</button>
    </center>
    </div>
    <div class=option>
    <center>
    <button type="button" onclick=exam() class="Bt_menu">Next Exams Details</button>
    </center>
    </div>
    <div class=option>
    <center>
    <button type="button" onclick=atten() class="Bt_menu">Attendance Details</button>
    </center>
    </div>
    <div class=option>
    <center>
    <button type="button" onclick=Result() class="Bt_menu">Exam Result Details</button>
    </center>
    </div>
    <div class=option>
    <center>
    <button type="button" onclick=Notices() class="Bt_menu">College Notices / Details</button>
    </center>
    </div>
</div>
<p id=Table></p>
</body>
</html>
```

in this page i used this script tage as :-

```
<script src="StInfo.jsp">
</script>
```

now i show u my StInfo.jsp file there are the java script method .

```
<%@page import="data.*;" %>
<%
ServletConfig con=getServletConfig();
ServletContext ctx=con.getServletContext();
DataRet d;
%>
function par()
{
try
{
// i sat ctx.setAttribute("id") is 1 already in my last page . so the output will be 1 of it .
<%DataRet.setAtt(""+ctx.getAttribute("id"),"stlogin");%>
var id=<%=ctx.getAttribute("id")%>                // if i did that than the value 1 store in id .
var id=<%=DataRet.get(2)%>                        // but when i did that nething happen and code didn't work .
}catch(err)
{
txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n";
txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n";
txt+="Click OK to continue.\n\n";
alert(txt);
}
//alert("id");
document.getElementById("Table").innerHTML="<center><table border='10'><th>College Id</th> <th>Name</th><th>Father Name</th><th>Department</th><th>Year</th><th>Semester</th><th>Ph. No.</th><th>Address</th>\
<tr>\
<td>"+id+"</td>\
<td>"+id+"</td>\
<td>"+id+"</td>\
<td>"+id+"</td>\
<td>"+id+"</td>\
<td>"+id+"</td>\
<td>"+id+"</td>\
<td>"+id+"</td>\
</tr></table><center>";


}
```

and here is my DataRet File ---

```
   package data;
import java.sql.*;
import connection.connection;
public class DataRet
{
static Connection c;
static ResultSet re;
static Statement s;
static String id;
static
{
    try
    {
        c=connection.getConnect();
        System.out.println(c);
        s = c.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Statement Object Created = "+s);
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
}
public static void setAtt(String table)
{
    try{
    re=s.executeQuery("select * from "+table);
    }catch(Exception e){}
}
public static void setAtt(String att,String table)
{
    System.out.println("Table Sated");
    id=att;
    int i=0;
    try
    {
        re=s.executeQuery("select * from "+table);

        while(re.next() && re.getString(3).equals(att))
        {
            i++;
            break;
        }
    System.out.println("curser on "+i);
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    }
    public static void change()
    {
        try{
            re.next();
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
    public static String get(int val)
    {
        System.out.println("value geted of "+val);
        try{
            String o=re.getString(val);
            //o=string.valueOf(o);
            System.out.println(o);
            return o;
        }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println("Problum in Geting Value"+e);}
        System.out.println("return null");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now the question is that when i call a method **<%=ctx.getAttribute("id")%> ** in stInfo.jsp then this method print 1 in very coloum . and when i call 
<%=DataRet.get(2)%>   method then file didn't work ....

Comment: And where is the question?

Comment: bro the problum and the question in par() js funtion who's in the StInfo.jsp ... soo i am also add the question at the last of my block .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storing of data from a JSP scriptlet should be pretty straight forward just like you have it.

```
var id=<%=ctx.getAttribute("id")%>
```

Although I would recommend you to be careful with the returning data, if it isn't a number for sure, then you must put it between quotes just to be sure the JS doesn't break. For example:

if `<%=DataRet.get(2)%>` returns a string `"TEST"` then the resulting JS would look like:

```
var id=TEST
```

And that would just simply break because there is no variable named TEST. You need to enclose it in double or single quotes like:

```
var id="<%=DataRet.get(2)%>";
```

Also you have to keep in mind the semicolons at the end of every line, and escape any possible chars that can break the JS code. Remember, the JS code has not been executed yet after the JSP has compiled, so it is like if you wrote that JS code manually.

If this code is not working start by checking what `<%=DataRet.get(2)%>` is returning, and also if there are any JS errors.

Hope it helps.

Comment: mojarras bro . u are the best . its work . yes its a tiny problem . and thanks to u now i can carry on my project ..... Thankssssss